# How to show progrss bar in highchart while loading data?

Tags: highcharts, progress-bar

I am loading chart using json but it takes while so meanwhile i want to show progress bar to show the process happening behind.

```
    $.getJSON('frontend/js/tmp/data40.json', function(data) {
           options.series=data; 
           var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

How can i show progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use showLoading function of highcharts to show progressbar.

```
yourChart.showLoading('Loading...');
yourChart.hideLoading();
```

will share a working demo

see the Alternate way of doing this , as you want to wait till response comes back and data fills in highchart see [Working demo on your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzsmLAfKuTPo61pDU2hn?p=preview)
You can style and position this "Loading data" text  or use a loading icon/spinner icon as you want.

```
 $("#container").text("Loading Data");
  $.getJSON('data10.json', function(data) {
    options.series=data;
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


});
```

Comment: hi
I checked example but it works using button only. http://jsfiddle.net/4t2n1hg0/8/  but it works on clicking button when i removed button it shows loading only. How can showloading should appear only during loading of plots while it should disappear afteer chart gets loaded

Comment: before the $.getJSON it should be showLoading and in success of that call when you fill the highcharts object use : hideLoading();